# CKEditor: Get rid of space on empty lines/paragraphs <p>&nbsp;</p>

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.5.9. So far its been a great experience, but I am kind of stuck at a point where it is adding an extra space (`&nbsp;`) in empty lines/paragraphs. See this: [This image shows what I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt41z.png)
Is there a way in CKEditor config I can get rid of this space in empty lines? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of the space ?

Comment: Because I want to use the content as text and precision is important.